# What is the system view for sys.syscolpars?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I am checking system base table at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx and system internal views at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189600(v=sql.105).aspx

For base table sys.syscolpars, is there a corresponding system view for it so that I can access its data without loginning in DAC mode?

Thanks

Comment: What information in `sys.syscolpars` are you looking fro that you can't find in other system views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent is `sys.columns`.

You can use

```
exec sys.sp_helptext 'sys.columns'
```

to see the underlying query used and how the columns are mapped.

```
CREATE VIEW sys.columns
AS
  SELECT c.id                                                             AS object_id,
         c.NAME,
         c.colid                                                          AS column_id,
         c.xtype                                                          AS system_type_id,
         c.utype                                                          AS user_type_id,
         c.length                                                         AS max_length,
         c.prec                                                           AS PRECISION,
         c.scale,
         CONVERT(SYSNAME, CollationPropertyFromId(c.collationid, 'name')) AS collation_name,
         sysconv(bit, 1 - ( c.status & 1 ))                               AS is_nullable,-- CPM_NOTNULL  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 2)                                       AS is_ansi_padded,-- CPM_NOTRIM  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 8)                                       AS is_rowguidcol,-- CPM_ROWGUIDCOL  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 4)                                       AS is_identity,-- CPM_IDENTCOL  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 16)                                      AS is_computed,-- CPM_COMPUTED  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 32)                                      AS is_filestream,-- CPM_FILESTREAM  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x020000)                                AS is_replicated,-- CPM_REPLICAT  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x040000)                                AS is_non_sql_subscribed,-- CPM_NONSQSSUB  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x080000)                                AS is_merge_published,-- CPM_MERGEREPL  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x100000)                                AS is_dts_replicated,-- CPM_REPLDTS  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 2048)                                    AS is_xml_document,-- CPM_XML_DOC   
         c.xmlns                                                          AS xml_collection_id,
         c.dflt                                                           AS default_object_id,
         c.chk                                                            AS rule_object_id,
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x1000000)                               AS is_sparse,-- CPM_SPARSE  
         sysconv(bit, c.status & 0x2000000)                               AS is_column_set -- CPM_SPARSECOLUMNSET  
  FROM   sys.syscolpars c
  WHERE  number = 0
         AND has_access('CO', c.id) = 1
```